# How do you modify a Delphi Panel so Alignment := taRightJustify renders Caption with slight right margin?

Tags: delphi, margin, caption

I am converting an old legacy program from 2005. It uses many Panel.Caption fields to store output. All of panels are set to taRightJustify. The caption is very tight up against the right edge.

As a quick fix I tried making border=4 and at first I thought this would be the solution. It gave the visual appearance of a inside right margin. However, characters with a descender such as "g, y, and comma.

So I'm looking for a way to modify the Panel.Caption property so when the panel is set to taRightJustify there is a little bit of margin between the right edge of the caption text and the inside right edge of the panel.

I thought about just adding a space to the end of the caption text but there are so many places where the caption text is actually numeric values and adding the extra space would cause for code changes than it's worth.

Comment: It's easy to achieve what you want, just not with a panel caption. Does it have to be done with panel caption?

Comment: If the panels are somehow aligned in their parents you can set AlignWithMargins to True and set Margins.Right to some value (say 4) while the other Margins are set to 0.

Comment: It could be useful to have an extract from a `.dfm` file of one such panel, to see exactly what properties you have set, and how. A possible cheat could be to override the `Paint` method.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan unfortunately yes. I was trying to avoid having to change out all the elements that are scattered through the old legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Konopka Signature VCL Controls 6.2.3 installed. I've decided to switch out all the panels using the taRightJustify setting for RzPanels. The RzPanel has a TextMargin property that does exactly what I need. Thank you Ray Kanopka for incorporating this feature into your panel component.

https://delphibydesign.com/
https://raize.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can modify how the TPanel displays its caption by changing the code that draws the text of the caption ... but you probably don't want to actually change that code.

Realistically what you can do is create a simple custom control which is a TPanel with another protected TPanel inside it.  The properties of the inner panel should use ParentColor := true no bevels, Aligned to client (so it fills the outer panel) and set the right Margin and AlignWithMargins as advised by @Uwe Raabe.

override the declaration of the Caption property so that when this is accessed it is accessing the Caption of the inner panel.

override the declaration of the ShowCaption Property so that the outer panel ShowCaption is always False and setting the property changes the ShowCaption property on the inner panel.

With Search and Replace change all of your TPanels to your new derived class (which you would have given your own name to - perhaps TPaddedPanel).

To use your new TPanel in the form designer of the IDE you will have to register the component.

There are lots of tutorials for creating custom components. Ray Konopka is very experienced and has a useful tutorial on VCL components at: https://edn.embarcadero.com/es/article/20569